# Console app not triggering ItemUpdated event in list

Tags: event-receivers, splistitem, list-item, console-application, itemupdated

I have created a console app in C# .Net. The app is updating two fields in an item in a list. The list has an eventreceiver and when the item is updated it copy every value from all fields to another item on a different site collection. The ItemUpdated event triggers just fine when I manually updates the item, and all values are copied correctly to the other item.

But when I update item via my console app it saves the new values to the item but it does not trigger the ItemUpdated event on the item?.

From my console app:

```
item["fieldName"] = value;
item.Update();
```

What do I need to do to trigger the event?

Comment: Are you logged in as the SharePoint App Pool account? Or using RunWithElevatedPrivileges in your code?

Comment: The code does not run with elevated privileges. I'm running the app with my administrator account that has full admin rights on the sharepoint portal.

Comment: for you console app, are u using CSOM / SSOM ?

Comment: I am using Server Side Object Model. Forgot to mention that the list that stores the item is in two places, different site collections. But it uses the same event receiver. ItemUpdated should be triggered but it doesn't. I've tried with Thread.Sleep(), no luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

the items which is created by/ modified by system account, workflow or event receiver will not apply.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using CSOM, do remember to call ClientContext.ExecuteQuery
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539976(v=office.14).aspx

```
string siteUrl = "http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection";

ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements");
ListItem oListItem = oList.Items.GetById(3);

oListItem["Title"] = "My Updated Title.";

oListItem.Update();

clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Is the reason my console app not triggering the ItemUpdated event on the item that it isn't in the sharepoint context somehow? Because when I debug attached to w3w.exe processes nothing happends.